# Regex matching url with a specific words

Tags: regex, apache

Using apache rewrite 
I want to redirect urls to a file with a specific patterns

```
images/gallery/photos/album/thumb/image.jpg
images/gallery/photos/album/view/image.jpg
images/gallery/photos/album/image.jpg
```

Using regex i want to match (photos/album/) as a part
Returns (thumb|view) if provided
And last returns the last part of the url (image.jpg)

My final approach is

```
^images/gallery/(.*/)*((view|thumb)/)+(.*)$
Array
(
    [1] => photos/album/
    [2] => thumb/
    [3] => image.jpg
)
```

Which works perfect if ONLY (view|thumb) is provided, but if replaced `+` with `?` the regex returns `images/gallery/thumb/` without passing (thumb) as a part

```
^images/gallery/(.*/)*((view|thumb)/)?(.*)$
Array
(
    [1] => photos/fresh-water-fish/thumb/
    [2] => 
    [3] => Plant_Aquarium.jpg
)
```

What is the best solution to get (view|thumb) `if` provided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
^images/gallery/((?:[^./]*/)*?)((view|thumb)/)?([^/]*)$
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uI3yI6/3)

Comment: Works like a charm, with an explanation demo you sir saved my day

Answer (score 1):

```
^images/gallery/(\w+/\w+)/?(view|thumb)?/?([^/]*)$
```

this one will match :

```
$1 : "photo/album"

$2 : "view", "thumb" or ""

$3 : "image.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using instead of 
`images/gallery/(.*/)*((view|thumb)/)?(.*)$`
this one:
`images/gallery/(.*/)*((view|thumb)?/)(.*)$`

I'm not shure why greedy regex '?' don't work on groups, but it works fine on specific value ('[1,2]', '.', '(text|text2)', etc.)

Comment: Thanx for help, but didn't work
And use you can use non-greedy `?` on groups like @karthik-manchala mentioned